# Faster way to take xor between one row and a matrix of 1's and 0's?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a row of data, say `A = [0 1 1 1 0 0]`.

Matrix B contains many rows.  For a dummy example let's say it's just `B = [1 1 1 0 1 0; 1 0 0 1 0 1]`.

I want to find the number of columns in which A and a row of B differ, and use that vector of differences to find which row of B is most similar to A.  So for the example above, A differs from `B(1,:)` in columns 1, 4, 5 = 3 total difference.  A differs from B(2,:) in columns 1, 2, 3, 6 = 4 total differences, and so I would want to return index 1 to indicate that A is most similar to B(1,:).

In reality B has **~50,000 rows**, and A and B both have about **800 columns**.  My current code to find the most similar row is below:

```
min(sum(xor(repmat(A,B_rows,1),B),2));
```

That works, but it's very slow.  Any insights into which function is taking so long and ways to improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 6 more or less similar approaches with `bsxfun`, hard to tell which one is the fastest.

```
%example data
A = [0 1 1 1 0 0];
B = perms(A);     %720x6 matrix
```

Counting similarities:

```
Z = sum(  bsxfun(@eq,  A,B) , 2);
Z = sum( ~bsxfun(@ne,  A,B) , 2);
Z = sum( ~bsxfun(@xor, A,B) , 2);
```

Counting differences:

```
Z = sum( ~bsxfun(@eq,  A,B) , 2);
Z = sum(  bsxfun(@ne,  A,B) , 2);
Z = sum(  bsxfun(@xor, A,B) , 2);
```

`Z` is a vector containing the number of equal/unequal elements of `A` for every row of `B`.

Benchmark for 100 trials each (same order as above):

```
t100 =

    0.0081
    0.0098
    0.0123
    0.0102
    0.0087
    0.0111
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) with `'hamming'` distance

```
[D I] = pdist2( A, B, 'hamming', 'Smallest', 1 );
```

Comment: In case it's not faster, it's at least a lot easier to understand.

Comment: Ahh ok that's a new function for me.  Thanks for all the answers everyone, this was very helpful.

Comment: @Shai: can you explain your solution, what is better compared to the others?  (at)user1956609 you have chosen the slowest, any reason for that? I'm just curios :)

Comment: Yeah the reason is I misread the decimal point and just sat through an hour of this running, ha.  Thanks for the update, trying the others soon.

Answer (score 2):

## Benchmark for all solutions

([Thanks to Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21047303/2605073) for the Benchmark-code)

```
function [t] = bench()
    A = [0 1 1 1 0 0];
    B = perms(A);

    % functions to compare
    fcns = {
        @() compare1(A,B);
        @() compare2(A,B);
        @() compare3(A,B);
        @() compare4(A,B);
    };

    % timeit
    t = zeros(4,1);
    for ii = 1:100;
        t = t + cellfun(@timeit, fcns);
    end
end

function Z = compare1(A,B)  %thewaywewalk
    Z = sum(  bsxfun(@eq,  A,B) , 2);
end
function Z = compare2(A,B)  %Matt J
    Z = sum(bsxfun(@xor, A, B),2);
end
function Z = compare3(A,B)  %Luis Mendo
    A = logical(A);
    Z = sum(B(:,~A),2) + sum(~B(:,A),2);
end
function Z = compare4(A,B)  %Shai
     Z = pdist2( A, B, 'hamming', 'Smallest', 1 );
end
```

result for 100 trials and a `720x6` matrix for `B`:

```
0.0068s   %thewaywewalk
0.0092s   %Matt J
0.0077s   %Luis Mendo
0.0399s   %Shai
```

result for 100 trials and a `40320x8` matrix for `B`:

```
0.0889s   %thewaywewalk
0.1512s   %Matt J
0.4571s   %Luis Mendo
0.4578s   %Shai
```

The `bsxfun` approach seems to be the fastest, and for that by using the anonymous function `@eq`.

Comment: you do not take into account that my solution gives as an output the nearest-neighbor: distance and index. It amounts to another call `[D I]=min(Z);` after each of all other candidates. I don't think this is going to change the timing results radically, but it may have an influence. Moreover, you might want to consider the effect of input type: setting `a

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the bsxfun command is what you need

```
min(sum(bsxfun(@xor, A, B),2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, which replaces `xor` by indexing (not sure if it's faster than previous answers):

```
A = logical(A);
min(sum(B(:,~A),2) + sum(~B(:,A),2))
```

Or, to avoid `~` on `B`:

```
A = logical(A);
min(sum(B(:,~A),2) - sum(B(:,A),2)) + nnz(A)
```