# Fastest way of generating a logical matrix by given row indices of true values?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

What is the most efficient way of generating

```
>> A

A =

     0     1     1
     1     1     0
     1     0     1
     0     0     0
```

with

```
>> B = [2 3; 1 2; 1 3]

B =

     2     3
     1     2
     1     3
```

in MATLAB?

E.g., `B(1, :)`, which is `[2 3]`, means that `A(2, 1)` and `A(3, 1)` are `true`.

My attempt still requires one for loop, iterating through `B`'s row. Is there a loop-free or more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of many, though [**`sub2ind`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) is the dedicated function for that:

```
%// given row indices
B = [2 3; 1 2; 1 3]
%// size of row index matrix
[n,m] = size(B)
%// size of output matrix
[N,M] = deal( max(B(:)), n)
%// preallocation of output matrix
A = zeros(N,M)
%// get col indices to given row indices
cols = bsxfun(@times, ones(n,m),(1:n).')
%// set values
A( sub2ind([N,M],B,cols) ) = 1
```

---

```
A =

     0     1     1
     1     1     0
     1     0     1
```

---

If you want a logical matrix, change the following to lines

```
A = false(N,M)
A( sub2ind([N,M],B,cols) ) = true
```

---

### Alternative solution

```
%// given row indices
B = [2 3; 1 2; 1 3];
%// number if rows
r = 4;  %// e.g. = max(B(:))
%// number if cols
c = 3;  %// size(B,1)

%// preallocation of output matrix
A = zeros(r,c);
%// set values
A( bsxfun(@plus, B.', 0:r:(r*(c-1))) ) = 1;
```

Comment: +1 for the use of sub2ind. Surprisingly, this is slower (measured by `tic toc`) than looping through `B`'s elements (my real `B` is `100x5`). Probably because `B` only has 500 elements, so it's actually more efficient to just loop through all of them?

Comment: @SibbsGambling 500 elements is small and its possible. But the use of `tic/toc` is inappropriate for benchmarks, [have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21121323/2605073) for a more appropriate benchmark using `timeit`.

Comment: @SibbsGambling I added an alternative solution which should be faster. Also for benchmark: make sure you didn't forgot any `;` :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way, **using the [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function**:

```
A = full(sparse(cumsum(ones(size(B))), B, 1));
```

This gives

```
A =
     0     1     1
     1     1     0
     1     0     1
```

If you need a **predefined number of rows** in the output, say `r` (in your example `r = 4`):

```
A = full(sparse(cumsum(ones(size(B))), B, 1, 4, size(B,1)));
```

which gives

```
A =
     0     1     1
     1     1     0
     1     0     1
     0     0     0
```

---

You can equivalently **use the [`accumarrray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) function**:

```
A = accumarray([repmat((1:size(B,1)).',size(B,2),1), B(:)], 1);
```

gives

```
A =
     0     1     1
     1     1     0
     1     0     1
```

Or with a **predefined number of rows**, `r = 4`,

```
A = accumarray([repmat((1:size(B,1)).',size(B,2),1), B(:)], 1, [r size(B,1)]);
```

gives

```
A =
     0     1     1
     1     1     0
     1     0     1
     0     0     0
```

Comment: +1; thanks for providing an alternative! I realize that in my real problem, just looping through `B` is faster than these methods... My real `B` is `100x5`. Probably because `B` only has 500 elements, so it's actually more efficient to just loop through all of them?

Comment: I don't know... Timing is always difficult. Whichever works best for you :-)