# finding all factors of a number

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, disp

I am new to Matlab and for the values of a, l and w i need to find all the values for l in the data set and the corresponding w values.

```
a=10;
l=(0:10)
w=(0:10)
for l,d
       if a == l.*w
           disp(l) 
           disp(w)
       end
end
```

Comment: your qustion isn't clear. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Please @user3636220, try to be more clear explaining what you need help with.

Comment: Without understanding your actual question, the title suggests that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028646/factorization-of-an-integer-number) may help.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to do, but I think your code could be put as follows:

```
a = 10;
l = 0:a; %// actually, it would suffice to check numbers up to floor(a/2)
ind = rem(a,l)==0; %// logical index that tells if remainder is zero or not
disp([l(ind); a./l(ind)])
```

Result:

```
     1     2     5    10
    10     5     2     1
```

---

You could do it more directly with Matlab's [`factor`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/symbolic/factor.html) function:

```
f = factor(a);
disp([f; a./f])
```

Result:

```
     2     5
     5     2
```

Comment: The `factor` function seems to be the way to go. If there is only interest in a restricted set of values, the output can afterwards be reduced. Check `help union`.