# Finding the shortest repetitive pattern in a string

Tags: regex, matlab, pattern-matching, octave, maple

I was wondering if there was a way to do pattern matching in Octave / matlab?  I know Maple 10 has commands to do this but not sure what I need to do in Octave / Matlab.  So if a number was `12341234123412341234` the pattern match would be `1234`. I'm trying to find the *shortest pattern that upon repetiton generates the whole string*.

Please note: the numbers (only numbers will be used) won't be this simple. Also, *I won't know the pattern ahead of time* (that's what I'm trying to find). Please see the [**Maple 10 example**](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=StringTools%2FPrimitiveRoot) below which shows that the pattern isn't known ahead of time but the command finds the pattern.

Example of Maple 10 pattern matching:

```
ns:=convert(12341234123412341234,string);

             ns := "12341234123412341234"

StringTools:-PrimitiveRoot(ns);

             "1234"
```

How can I do this in Octave / Matlab?
Ps: I'm using Octave 3.8.1

Comment: Nobody is going to look up the Maple example. Please provide the relevant information in the question. For example, you should add that the command should find the pattern for you...

Comment: is the length of the pattern known and fixed? and does the input string only contains the pattern or also other characters?

Comment: @thewaywewalk No, the length of the pattern isn't known. The string is only numbers.   Please note: the numbers (only numbers will be used) won't be this simple nor will I know it's pattern ahead of time (that's what I'm trying to find).

Comment: my question is: could the string be `1234912348123471234612345`  and would the desired pattern to find also be `1234`?

Comment: @thewaywewalk yes the desired pattern to find would still be 1234

Comment: Well, it's still not clear. If there are multiple patterns possible, which one you want detected: the longest one? the pattern with the most occurences? what would be the minimal length then? Imagine `1234123412341234123` than you would find `1234` four times, but `123` five times and actually `1234123412341234123` is also a pattern. Please provide a much better example, which covers all special cases.

Comment: @thewaywewalk sorry if I wasn't clear yes I want the longest pattern possible.  So if a number was 12341234123412341234 the pattern match would be 1234.  I'll type it out in words instead of just showing the numbers example and add it to the question

Comment: But the longest pattern possible of '12341234123412341234 ' **is** '12341234123412341234 ' and the second longest is '1234123412341234123 ' - so if you state the your real input is not as simple as your example, please post your real input :)

Comment: @thewaywewalk the whole question is about not knowing the pattern of numbers and finding one.  I gave an example along with the answer with numbers and with written text.   Your asking me to tell you all possible combinations there might be...if I knew that I would be working on wall street :-)

Comment: I think the point @thewaywewalk is making is that, if we allow other words to delimit the pattern you are looking for, the solution is ambiguous: do we match only `1234`, or do we match all of `1234912348123471234612345`? How is the program supposed to know which is the better result?

Comment: @eigenchris yes we only match 1234.  How to match it with just 1234, I wish I knew how maple 10 does it with just 2 lines of code.

Comment: @RickT Please be aware that the you will lose your reps for this question if there are more than 10 edits so don't do any more edits.

Comment: @kkuilla I've stopped editing but if you take a look others are making really good changes :-)

Comment: @RickT It was just to make you aware (in case you didn't know) that one more edit and you will lose the reps..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To find the shortest pattern that upon repetition generates the whole string, you can use regular expressions as follows:

```
result = regexp(str, '^(.+?)(?=\1*$)', 'match');
```

Some examples:

```
>> str = '12341234123412341234';
>> result = regexp(str, '^(.+?)(?=\1*$)', 'match')
result = 
    '1234'

>> str = '1234123412341234123';
>> result = regexp(str, '^(.+?)(?=\1*$)', 'match')
result = 
    '1234123412341234123'

>> str = 'lullabylullaby';
>> result = regexp(str, '^(.+?)(?=\1*$)', 'match')
result = 
    'lullaby'

>> str = 'lullaby1lullaby2lullaby1lullaby2';
>> result = regexp(str, '^(.+?)(?=\1*$)', 'match')
result = 
    'lullaby1lullaby2'
```

Comment: Was just about to write this. +1.

Comment: Nice. I was having trouble constructing a regex for this.

Comment: @eigenchris So was I :-) Credit for all my answers about `regexp` should go to [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)! BTW I borrowed your examples

Comment: and why is the result for `str = '12341235123412351234';` **not** `'1234`? Regarding one of my comments it should. I ***really*** don't get that question. And I tried really hard.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Because `1234` repeated doesn't generate `str`. That `str` doesn't have a repeating pattern, other than the whole string itself

Comment: @RickT The edit you made to the question states that you are looking for the `longest pattern possible`? You have accepted this answer even though it gives you the shortest. Your edit isn't clear. What is it you are actually after? Longest or shortest?

Comment: I think that while the OP's problem statement is ambiguous, this is probably the answer they are looking for. It meets the specification of the equivalent Maple command [`PrimativeRoot()`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=StringTools%2FPrimitiveRoot).

Comment: @eigenchris The Maple link really clarifies the issue. The OP should edit the answer with this

Comment: So the OP **is** looking for the minimum length. Could someone with enough reps edit the question to reflect that. And please, format it properly.

Comment: @LuisMendo I finally agree that your answer is an equivalent of the Maple function. But without looking that up, it wasn't clear to me, that the pattern must be repeated directly.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Yes, the original question left a lot to imagination

Comment: @LuisMendo we really should introduce the Mentalist award ;)

Comment: @kkuilla I've edited to reflect that. As for the format, well, I wouldn't know how to do it without rewriting it too much...

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. Get rid of the bold stuff. I really have to get to 2k :-)

Comment: @thewaywewalk Hahaha. Pity that we haven't (yet) found a way to automatically assign a question the "mentalism needed" trait

Comment: @kkuilla Done. You are right, it looks better now. I've only used cursive for the two key sentences

Comment: @LuisMendo Title? `Finding the shortest repetitive pattern in a string`?

Comment: @LuisMendo Brilliant. That was a lot of edits... :-)

Comment: @kkuilla Perfect title. You'll make a very good editor soon :-)

Comment: Umm, this is a *little* faster than my answer (only by a factor of > x30), but is this really really *MATLAB*? ;-)

Comment: The OP strikes again into our hearts and minds to confuse us.... And out from the ashes of all of this confusion is born a mentalist whose sole purpose is to undo the confusion brought into this world. Several others are begotten from this very event thus creating... The league of mentalists. Go mentalists go!

Comment: On another note, I now know what positive and negative lookahead/lookbehind are in regex's. Thanks @LuisMendo!

Comment: @TryHard Hahaha, regular expressions are a world of their own!

Comment: @rayryeng We desperately need that badge created!

Comment: @eigenchris Yes, that's a very handy feature of regexps; as are are (numbered) backreferences

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this can be accomplished with regular expressions. Here is a script that will do what you need in the case of a repeated word called `pattern`.

It loops through the characters of a string called `str`, trying to match against another string called `pattern`. If matching fails, the `pattern` string is extended as needed.

**EDIT**: I made the code more compact.

```
str = 'lullabylullabylullaby';

pattern = str(1);
matchingState = false;
sPtr = 1;
pPtr = 1;

while sPtr <= length(str)
     if str(sPtr) == pattern(pPtr) %// if match succeeds, keep looping through pattern string
            matchingState = true;
            pPtr = pPtr + 1;
            pPtr = mod(pPtr-1,length(pattern)) + 1;
     else                          %// if match fails, extend pattern string and start again
            if matchingState
                sPtr = sPtr - 1;   %// don't change str index when transitioning out of matching state
            end  
            matchingState = false;
            pattern = str(1:sPtr);
            pPtr = 1;
     end

     sPtr = sPtr + 1;

end

display(pattern);
```

The output is:

```
pattern =

lullaby
```

---

**Note:**

This doesn't allow arbitrary delimiters between occurrences of the `pattern` string. For example, if `str = 'lullaby1lullaby2lullaby1lullaby2';`, then

```
pattern =

lullaby1lullaby2
```

This also allows the `pattern` to end mid-way through a cycle without changing the result. For example, `str = 'lullaby1lullaby2lullaby1';` would still result in

```
pattern =

lullaby1lullaby2
```

To fix this you could add the lines

```
if pPtr ~= length(pattern)
    pattern = str;
end
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Jan This is MATLAB, a language primarily used by engineers and scientists for numerical computations. The accepted solution is much better an uses regular expressions, which most languages support.

Comment: Thanks. Hard to find good documentation about this language. I am trying to convert it to C#. What does the lines "pattern = str(1);" and "pattern = str(1:sPtr);" and "if str(sPtr) == pattern(pPtr)" exactly do? I converted it to resp. "string pattern = s.Substring(0,1);", "pattern = s.Substring(0, sPtr);" and "if (s.Substring(sPtr) == pattern.Substring(pPtr))". I also noticed that Matlab strings are 1-based instead of zero-based in C#.

Comment: @Jan It looks like you've converted the code more or less correctly. If you are struggling with this, I would recommend you open a new question.
Again, for searching for patterns in text, I highly recommend you learn regular expressions, (C# supports them) and using one of the regex strings in the accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer using regular expression doesn't work in all cases. My first solution was using regular expressions but it failed on very big strings. But I have your code running now. I am now trying to iterate upon it so it supports input strings like "1666666" so that it will return 6.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is as follows:

1. determine length of string, and find all possible factors of the string length value
2. for each possible factor length, reshape the string and check
   for a repeated substring

To find all possible factors, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028646/factorization-of-an-integer-number) solution on SO. The next step can be performed in many ways, but I implement it in a simple loop, starting with the smallest factor length.

```
function repeat = repeats_in_string(str);
ns = numel(str);
nf = find(rem(ns, 1:ns) == 0);
for ii=1:numel(nf)
    repeat = str(1:nf(ii));
    if all(ismember(reshape(str,nf(ii),[])',repeat)); 
        break;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a great Rorschach test for your approach to problem solving. I'll add a signal engineering solution, which should be simple since the signal is expected to be perfectly repetitive, assuming this holds: *find the shortest pattern that upon repetition generates the whole string.*

In the following `str` fed to the function is actually a column vector of floats, not a string, the original string having been converted with `str2num(str2mat(str)')`:

```
function res=findshortestrepel(str);
[~,ii] = max(fft(str-mean(str)));
res = str(1:round(numel(str)/(ii-1)));
```

I performed a small test, comparing this to the `regexp` solution and found it to be faster overall (blue squares), although somewhat inconsistently, and only if you don't consider the time required to convert the string into a vector of floats (green squares). However I did not pursue this further (not breaking records with this):

[image]

Times in sec.