# How to replace repetitive punctuation in PHP using regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, repeat, find-replace

Let say, I have this

```
Hello ??? WHERE ARE YOU!!!! Comon ?!?!?!
desired outout
Hello ? WHERE ARE YOU!!!! Comon ?!
```

How can I achieve this? I tried `preg_replace_callback` but to no luck.  I used [Finding the shortest repetitive pattern in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963384/finding-the-shortest-repetitive-pattern-in-a-string) as an starting point but it works on complete sentence, I need it to work on word by word + I need to remove duplicate computations only (patterns)? [Live Code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4d4fe41211207c06e644ec62aede416309f5ef6)

Comment: Why is the desired output not "Hello ? WHERE ARE YOU! Comon ?!"?

Comment: @erisco need to clean up text which has ?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!, !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!, ???!!!???!!! etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
$str = "Hello ??? WHERE ARE YOU!!!! Comon ?!?!?! ...";

$replacement = [
    '?',
    '?!',
    '.',
];

foreach( $replacement as $key => $value ){
    $pattern[$key] = sprintf("/(\%s)+/", $value);
}

echo $outout = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

Insert any punctuation to replacement array to delete repetitive punctuation.

Comment: can this improved to use bunch of punctuation [.!?] and find repetitive pattern automatically?

Comment: Code updated. To delete any repetitive sign, add it to replacement array.

Comment: btw can you think of a way to find the repetitive pattern by itself as asked in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963384/finding-the-shortest-repetitive-pattern-in-a-string) and apply it in PHP? I tried but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\?+` with `?`, `!+` with `!`, `(\?!)+` with `?!`, and so on.

```
function dedup_punctuation($str) {
  $targets      = array('/\?+/', '/!+/', '/(\?!)+/');
  $replacements = array('?'    , '!'   , '?!'      );
  return preg_replace($targets, $replacements, $str);
}
```

Comment: This works but is there a way to find repetitive pattern automatically with using back reference etc? For this I have to enter every use case separately.