# Split string with plus sign as a delimiter

Tags: c#, string, parsing, split

I have an issue with a string containing the plus sign (+).
I want to split that string (or if there is some other way to solve my problem)

```
string ColumnPlusLevel = "+-J10+-J10+-J10+-J10+-J10";
string strpluslevel = ""; 
strpluslevel = ColumnPlusLevel; 
string[] strpluslevel_lines = Regex.Split(strpluslevel, "+");

foreach (string line in strpluslevel_lines)
{
    MessageBox.Show(line);
    strpluslevel_summa = strpluslevel_summa + line;
}   

MessageBox.Show(strpluslevel_summa, "summa sumarum");
```

The MessageBox is for my testing purpose.

Now... The ColumnPlusLevel string can have very varied entry but it is always a repeated pattern starting with the plus sign.
i.e. "+MJ+MJ+MJ" or "+PPL14.1+PPL14.1+PPL14.1" as examples.
(It comes form Another software and I cant edit the output from that software)

How can I find out what that pattern is that is being repeated?
That in this exampels is the +-J10 or +MJ or +PPL14.1

In my case above I have tested it by using only a MessageBox to show the result but I want the repeated pattering stored in a string later on.

Maybe im doing it wrong by using Split, maybe there is another solution.
Maybe I use Split in the wrong way.

Hope you understand my problem and the result I want.

Thanks for any advice.

/Tomas

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You did post code, but I cannot tell *what exactly* you want to achieve. Do you like what's presented in your message boxes? If not, why not? What do you *want*?

Comment: Please be more specific on the input and desired output; it is a bit unclear from the current formulation of the question.

Comment: Why does everybody want to use Regex for simple problems that can use string method : string[] strpluslevel_lines = strpluslevel.Split(new char[] { '+'});

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code. What isn't working?

Comment: You may be able to use regex to determine the shortest repeating pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963384/finding-the-shortest-repetitive-pattern-in-a-string

Comment: Will you need to know how often the pattern repeated?

Answer (score 5):

> How can I find out what that pattern is that is being repeated?

Maybe i didn't understand the requirement fully, but isn't it easy as:

```
string[] tokens = ColumnPlusLevel.Split(new[]{'+'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string first = tokens[0];
bool repeatingPattern = tokens.Skip(1).All(s => s == first);
```

If `repeatingPattern` is `true` you know that the pattern itself is `first`.

> Can you maybe explain how the logic works

The line which contains `tokens.Skip(1)` is a LINQ query, so you need to add `using System.Linq` at the top of your code file. Since `tokens` is a `string[]` which implements `IEnumerable<string>` you can use any LINQ (extension-)method. `Enumerable.Skip(1)` will *skip* the first because i have already stored that in a variable and i want to know if all others are same. Therefore i use `All` which returns `false` as soon as one item doesn't match the condition(so one string is different to the first). If all are same you know that there is a repeating pattern which is already stored in the variable `first`.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Can you maybe explain how the logic works in the Bool line. 
Might be good to know if any tweaking is needed later on. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) function :

```
string pattern = ColumnPlusLevel.Split("+")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...but it is always a repeated pattern starting with the plus sign.

Why do you even need String.Split() here if the pattern always only repeats itself?

```
string input = @"+MJ+MJ+MJ";

int indexOfSecondPlus = input.IndexOf('+', 1);
string pattern = input.Remove(indexOfSecondPlus, input.Length - indexOfSecondPlus);
//pattern is now "+MJ"
```

No need of string split, no need to use LinQ

Answer (score 0):

`String` has a method called `Split` which let's you split/divide the string based on a given character/character-set:

```
string givenString = "+-J10+-J10+-J10+-J10+-J10"'

string SplittedString = givenString.Split("+")[0] ///Here + is the character based on which the string would be splitted and 0 is the index number

string result = SplittedString.Replace("-","") //The mothod REPLACE replaces the given string with a targeted string,i added this so that you can get the numbers only from the string
```